# Checking value before updating data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm writing an ASP.NET web application with Entity Framework, and I was wondering what would be the correct way to check the values of an entity before it's updated with the new value - in this case, to check if the user to request the update is the one associated with the entity.

```
public IHttpActionResult PutUserRatings(int id, UserRatings userRatings)
{
    var um = new UserManager(db);
    //Does this part get the entity already in the database, or does it point to the new data? 
    if (db.Entry(userRatings).Entity.UserId != um.User.Id)
    {
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
    db.Entry(userRatings).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

So in short, the question is if the above code works as intended, and if not, should I rather request the original entity with `db.UserRatings.Find(id)`?

EDIT: The question is due to the ambiguity of the documentation, and the fact that I have no database ready to verify my idea.

Comment: I don't think it's clear how you want the code to work can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I want to check the user ID of the entry I'm updating to see if it matches the user that is logged on (to verify that the user can indeed modify the said entry). But to do this, I obviously want to check the userId in the database, not in the received new value. I'm not sure if `db.Entry(userRatings).Entity` gives back the old or the new values or the old ones.